# How to draw/paint UIIMage on view as paint without UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm developing painting app in this app I'm using ACEDrawing tool to draw over the view. But I've to cut particular portion of the painting and to paste at anywhere on the view.
I can copy the paintings of the view as an image. my code is here.

In .h file

@property (strong,nonatomic)ACEDrawingView *DrawingViews;

@property (nonatomic, strong)UIScrollView *myScrollView;

in .m file

```
//creating the Drawing view
    _DrawingViews = [[ACEDrawingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.testView.frame.size.width, self.testView.frame.size.height)];
    _DrawingViews.drawTool=ACEDrawingToolTypePen;
    _DrawingViews.tag=i;
    _DrawingViews.delegate=self;
    [myScrollView addSubview:_DrawingViews];
```

After Inside Copy method.

-(void)copy:(id)sender{

```
ACEDrawingView *dragView = [self.myScrollView viewWithTag:currentTag];// Getting ACEDrawing View with tag
CGSize size = [_userResizableView1 bounds].size;//just for size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[[dragView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(200,200, 145, 150)];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

}

But, I can paste it only as an image using UIImageView. I don't know how to paste it as a painting overview then only I can erase or redraw.

-Gratefull to Mr.Duncan sir and all who will answer.

Answer (score 0):

UIImage has various drawing methods like drawInRect. You've already figured out how to create a graphics context. You could use `drawInRect` To draw your image into the graphics context.

(Note that you want to use the longer form of begin image context that takes a scale and options. (I'm not at my Mac to look up the function name.) If you pass in a scale of 0 it creates a Retina context on Retina devices. With the code you're using it will degrade retina images to non-retina resolution.)

Comment: k mr duncan I'tried it but its not working, NOTE:-Actually I've to draw it on dynamically created view over the main view.

Comment: You need to edit your post and provide a lot more information about what you're doing and how you're doing it. When is the code you posted being called? What are you doing with the images that it generates?